# Change from domain.com/project TO project.domain.com

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have created a subdomain 'project' within my domain through cpanel. Now, domain.com/project works fine. But I want the following:

project.domain.com

Do I need to do some activities in WHM login for achieving the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify me , whether now project.domain.com is working or not . As creating a subdomain project at domain.com is just enough to view project.subdomain.com. if you face any issues . kindly can you provide me the exact URL so that i can check the dns stuffs .

Comment: Yes project.domain.com is certainly not working.

Comment: http://vooopindia.com/test works. But not test.vooopindia.com

Comment: it works for me well . check this link for screenshot http://postimg.org/image/n2xgjr1lt/   , can you flush your dns and check at your end .